# How to increase maximum token size in a Hugging face model?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, openai-whisper

I'm **unable to get more than a few character of transcription using a finetuned whisper ai** model. I'm using google colab to run this. I tried max_new_token but it is returning an error if I enter a value above 400(approx). And 400 is definitely not a lot. **I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to increase the output size to file size; i.e. transcribing to the length of the audio file)**
here's the code that I'm running

```
print(pipe("/content/path_to_file", max_new_tokens=1000))
```

**its returning this error if max_new_token is exceeded 400(approx)**

```
in greedy_search(self, input_ids, logits_processor, stopping_criteria, max_length, pad_token_id, eos_token_id, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, output_scores, return_dict_in_generate, synced_gpus, streamer, **model_kwargs)
       2370                 continue  # don't waste resources running the code we don't need
       2371 
    -> 2372             next_token_logits = outputs.logits[:, -1, :]
       2373 
       2374             # pre-process distribution
    
    IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The error here is about the `token limitations` of the model since it can handle just not more than 400 tokens, that is why set the token to be more than 400 tokens will result in error. In ASR, tokens generally represent smaller units of audio data, such as phonemes, subword units, or even individual audio samples. however, what I recommend you is to do one of these following:

1. `Chunking`: If the text representation of your video is too large,
   and what you want is to use `openai-whisper` model to handle your
   task. you can divide it into smaller chunks and process them
   separately. You can split the video transcript into multiple
   segments and send them to the model one by one.
2. `Use a Different Model`: If your use case requires handling large
   texts, but did not rely on any specific model. frequently, you can
   consider using a model with a larger token limit or a model
   specifically designed for long text sequences instead. This requires some research about the model token's limit to find an appropriate model, but that is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

If increasing max_new_tokens isn't an option, an alternative approach could be to split your input audio file into smaller segments and process them in a loop. This way, you can manage the tokenization within the limits while still achieving your desired outcome.
[https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies](https://link)